# Opacity contrl for mapbox map with several layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

This is an example of how opacity can be changed for a Mapbox.JS map:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/opacity/

The example shows only one layer used.

With barely any experience in JavaScript, h**ow would I go about changing the opacity of the active base layer, if I have multiple of them?**

I have this now:

```
 L.control.layers({
    'Name of layer': L.tileLayer('/tiles1/z{z}/{y}/{x}.png').addTo(map),
    'Name of other layer': L.tileLayer('/tiles2/z{z}/{y}/{x}.png')
    }).addTo(map);
```

How to correctly set the variable to the selected layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to set the layers object to its own variable:

```
var myLayers = {
    'Name of layer': L.tileLayer('/tiles1/z{z}/{y}/{x}.png').addTo(map),
    'Name of other layer': L.tileLayer('/tiles2/z{z}/{y}/{x}.png')
};
L.control.layers(myLayers).addTo(map);
```

You could then set the opacity to either layer at any time with something like the following:

```
myLayers['Name of layer'].setOpacity(.8);
myLayers['Name of other layer'].setOpacity(.3);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! 
For others, here is the code: http://pastebin.com/RsvYrwKz

here is the result: http://vesture.dodies.lv

Comment: Happy to help @normis.  And thanks for posting your working solution!